# Objective C - NSDateFormatter returns nil?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss"];
self.date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

the code works fine with this string

- "2007-06-10 06:31:54.935"

but doesn't work with this one (it returns nil if the time is set to 0):

- "2007-06-10 00:00:00.000"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"` (uppercase S for the fractional seconds).
See [Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) guide.